# How to remove some words from a string

Tags: java

I want to remove certain words from a string. The words I want to remove are: "a", "an", "and", "the", "of", and "or".

I used the following method:

```
 void doNoiseEliminator(Vector<String> input){

        noNoiseLines = new Vector<String>();
        String temp;   

        for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {

            String regex = "(\\sand\\s)|(\\sa\\s)|(\\sthe\\s)|(\\san\\s)|(\\sof\\s)|(\\sor\\s)";
            temp = input.get(i).replaceAll(regex, " ");
            noNoiseLines.add(temp);            
        }
    }
```

But this does not seem to work. My program takes a string line and circular shifts the line.

For the following input :

MY NAME IS JOHN 
MY NAME IS AN A SAM 
MY NAME IS OR RAW

Output is :

1. a sam my name is
2. is a sam my name
3. is john my name
4. is raw my name
5. john my name is
6. my name is a sam
7. my name is john
8. my name is raw
9. name is a sam my
10. name is john my
11. name is raw my
12. raw my name is
13. sam my name is a

Why is this happening? How can I correct this? Please help me. Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be truthful I didnt understand your question fully, but try the simple way first, without regex, your problem might be there. Then go optimizing it if needed.

For example, try something like this.

void doNoiseEliminator(Vector input){

```
    noNoiseLines = new Vector<String>();
    String temp;   

    for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {


        temp = input.get(i).replaceAll(" a ", " ").replaceAll(" an ", " ").replaceAll(" and ", " ").replaceAll(" the ", " ").replaceAll(" of ", " ").replaceAll(" or ", " ");
        noNoiseLines.add(temp);            
    }
}
```

Of course this shouldnt be the final solution, its just to check if it works. Working, you can go towards checking/fixing the regex or any other solution.

Hope it helped to guide to the solution, cya.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Some are corrected but still if I entered a input like "MY NAME IS JOHN A A" output will "a my name is john".

Answer (score 1):

Hey use like this -

```
 noNoiseLines = new Vector<String>();
String temp;   

for(int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {


    temp = input.get(i).replaceAll(" and|an|a|the|of|or ", " ");
    noNoiseLines.add(temp);            
}
```

}

Put first **and** then **an** then **a** . if you put **a** before **an** it will replace all occurance of **a** including word containing **an** with "" and only remain is **n**.